# C++ require function without implicit conversion

Tags: c++, c++20, implicit-conversion, c++-concepts, visitor-pattern

I'm using `boost::variant` to imitate inheritance with value semantics.

There is one class that may be printed:

```cpp
struct Printable { /* ... */ };

void print(const Printable &) { /* ... */ }
```

And class that may not:

```
struct NotPrintable { /* ... */ };
```

Finally, there is "`Base`" class with implicit cast:

```cpp
struct Base : boost::variant<Printable, NotPrintable>
{
    Base(const Printable &) {}    // constructor for implicit cast
    Base(const NotPrintable &) {} // constructor for implicit cast
};

// Print, if printable, throw exception, if not
void print(const Base &base) 
{ 
    Printer printer{};
    base.apply_visitor(printer);
}
```

The problem is how to check for printable inside of visitor:

```
struct Printer
{
   using result_type = void;

   // If printable 
   template<typename PrintableType> requires 
   requires(const PrintableType &v) { {print(v)}; }  // (1)
   void operator()(const PrintableType &v) { print(v); }

   // If not printable
   void operator()(const auto &v) { throw /*...*/; }
};
```

Requirement `(1)` is always true due-to implicit conversion to `const Base &`. How to avoid conversion only in that exact place?

Comment: make the constructors explicit?

Comment: Then it won't be inheritance-like

Comment: You can add extra overload `template <typename T>void print(const T&) = delete;`?

Comment: I'm not sure how this one must work. Could you explain?

Comment: Actually, in my real application there are a lot of functions and overloaded operators for types. `print` was used as the most simple example.

Comment: Yeah, whatever. I will correct it

Comment: `print(NotPrintable{})` would select `print<NotPrintable>` which is deleted. so constraints would fail.

Comment: @Jarod42 ok, but will it work if sometimes i want a conversion? For example, for types `Integer` and `Boolean` there is no `operator+(Integer, Boolean)`, but there is implicit conversion `Boolean` -> `Integer` and `operator+(Integer, Integer)`

Comment: I only want to forbid call to `operator+(Base, Base)`

Comment: `operator+(Base, Base) = delete;`?

Comment: I can't define that operator and delete it at the same time :)

Comment: My idea was that `Base{Type1{}} + Base{Type2{}}` would resolve to `Type1{} + Type2{}` if some `operator+` fits (except `operator+(Base, Base)`, of course. Otherwise, it's infinite recursion)

Comment: I may change interface to `Base::add(Base{Type1{}}, Base{Type2{}})` but it's just worse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a perfect [solution](https://godbolt.org/z/x7r8WK1fc) that is based on **Inline friend definition**.

According to standard:

> Such a function is implicitly an inline function (10.1.6). **A friend function defined in a class is in the (lexical)
> scope of the class in which it is defined.** A friend function defined outside the class is not (6.4.1).

---

Some other things that may work:

1. **Deleted template function**

   ```cpp
   void print(auto) = delete;
   ```

cons:

- Boilerplate for every function
- <s>Forbids **all** implicit conversions</s>

  ```
  struct Boolean;

  struct String;

  struct Integer
  {
    Integer(Boolean);

    friend Integer operator+(Integer, Integer);
  }

  template<class T, class U>
  requires (!std::convertible_to<U, T>)
  void operator+(T, U) = delete;

  Integer + Integer // OK
  Integer + String  // ERROR (as expected)
  Integer + Boolean // OK
  ```

2. **Change interface**

   ```cpp
   struct Base : /* ... */
   {
     /* ... */

     static void print(Base);
   }
   ```

cons:

- No operators support (`Base + Base` -> `Base::add(Base, Base)`)
- Interface a little bit worse

3. **Add traits**

   ```
   template<typename T> struct Traits {
     static constexpr bool is_printable = true;
   }
   ```

cons:

- Boilerplate for every class and method
- How to handle implicit conversion (`Boolean + Integer`)?
- Closed for extension

Answer (score 1):

As @Jarod42 said in the comments, in order to ensure that implicit conversion does not occur, you need to define a template `print()` function to "absorb" other types (`NotPrintable` in your example) and set it to delete

```
void print(const auto&) = delete;
```

Then the `printable` concept can be defined as

```
template<class T>
concept printable = requires (const T& x) { print(x); };
```

which requires the expression `print(x)` to be well-formed.

When the type of `T` is `Printable` or `Base`, the expression `print(x)` is valid since you have defined the corresponding `print()` function for them. When the type of `T` is `NotPrintable` or other types, the deleted `print()` will be invoked which makes the expression ill-formed, so that the constraint is not satisfied.

Then you can use this concept to constrain `Printer::operator()`

```
struct Printer {
  using result_type = void;

  // If printable 
  template<printable PrintableType>
  void operator()(const PrintableType& v) { print(v); }

  // If not printable
  void operator()(const auto&) { throw /*...*/; }
};
```

Note that since `print(const auto&)` can be instantiated to *any* type, this will prohibit *all* implicit conversions, but we can still allow some implicit conversions by adding constraints to it

```
#include <concepts>

struct Boolean { };
struct Integer {
  Integer();
  Integer(Boolean);
  friend Integer operator+(Integer, Integer);
};
struct String { };

template<class T, class U>
  requires (!std::convertible_to<U, T>)
void operator+(T, U) = delete;

int main() {
  Integer{} + Integer{}; // OK
  Integer{} + String{};  // ERROR (as expected)
  Integer{} + Boolean{}; // OK
};
```

Comment: Good, but that forbids all implicit conversions

Comment: You might be able to constrain `void print(const auto&)` to allow *some* implicit conversions.

Comment: Would you kindly provide an example?

Comment: @gavrilikhin.d. See [this](https://godbolt.org/z/s8EnK8KGY) which based on your example.

Comment: Thanks! That's almost solve every problem!

Comment: I guess, that approach allows to reach the same functionality as I want for the cost of boilerplate.